# Verify Localizable.strings files contain the same keys

Tags: ios, localization

I wonder whether is possible to automatically check for the availability of the keys among all the localizable.strings files: is there a way to check that all the keys available in the base file are also available in every Localizable.strings?

Comment: Not with built-in tools. I've built myself a python script for a very similar situation.